# Unable to connect to home wireless network, but connects to others and other devices connect to this network

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm having a weird wifi connectivity problem. My computer is suddenly unable to connect to my home network. Other devices can connect to this network fine, and my computer can connect to all other networks fine, it's just my computer with this one network. It recognizes the network with good signal strength, but it doesn't connect.

I had been using this home network for months without any problems. I don't remember exactly what I was doing at the time, probably streaming some tv show or something, and my computer suddenly disconnected, so I don't think there were any changes made on my end. For a couple weeks there was intermittent connectivity (like an hour or two a day), but now it won't connect at all. I share the router with a few other people in my building, and no one else has had any problems. My phone also connects without any problems. I've tried connecting to other networks at my friends' apartments and at my school and everything works normally. Naturally, I've restarted the computer and the router several times. I've reentered the password countless times and I'm positive it's correct.

Also, I don't know if this information is useful, but I dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04, and neither are able to connect.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be going on here?